# Database design: Best Way to store heterogeneous subtypes of a parent class?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

Website has products with different categories 
(Phones, tablets, Washing machines, ... etc)

- Each product will have diff. prices depending on the store (If the user views Galaxy S4 16GB it will show $X for Xstore and $Y for Ystore)
- The website will have heavy filtration. For instance phones might be filtered according to price, color, .. etc. also filtered by manufactures or stores. (All samsung products, all products at Xstore, ... etc)
- For that reason Specs of each category should be stored separately (Phones: ScreenSize, Memory, Os, ... etc. watches will have different spec ..).
- Each category (Phones or watches) is expected to have ~1000+ product.

***Question:***

I first thought of a pyramid-like design. One table for all products then adding general table for each category with the common specifications (For Phones it will have screen-size, Os, ..), then a third table for variations (Memory:16GB or 32GB, Price at each store, ... etc).

Problem is: The main table with all the products will be very large (thousands), and with heavy filtrations I will have to go back and forth between three tables at least, and If I'm filtering samsung products, I will have to deal with more table (tablets, laptops, ... etc). 
I'm not sure whether it will go well from a performance point of view.

So I thought of the straight forward way; creating one single table for each category. Even variations will be duplicated (Galaxy S4 16GB and 32GB are 2 rows and even 16GB price at Xstore and Ystore will be in 2rows). I know it violates normalisation. But the table can barely exceed 1000 rows that way, I'll end up having much simpler code, and I think it will be performance efficient so I don't even need to index. The only case where I need to deal with all tables is when I'm filtering by manufacturer so I'll 've to grab Samsung tablets, phones, etc..

Sorry for elaborating, I was trying to make it as clear as possible as I don't have the schemas. Your patience is really appreciated and I'm open to new suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

---

### EDIT

The questions is categorization (only one level Phones, tablets, ..etc) each in a separate table VS all in one table and subs for category and diff attributes or specs. It's a performance question.

Comment: Could the same product have different attributes for different stores or do products differ based on teh attribute (128 meg IPAD vs 256 meg) same product different attributes or different products?

Comment: 128 GB IPAD is $1000 at store X.
128 GB IPAD is $990 at store y.
256 GB IPAD is $1200 at store Y

Comment: The first 2 are the same product but diff prices at diff stores. The third is another product.

Answer (score 0):

category sub category can be a single table with parent child relation which help to have as many sub levels

or list all category in one table and another table to just specify relation

```
id category parent
1 samsung    0
2 note       1
3  apple     0
4 ipad       3
```

store is sperate table
products will be another table with category id as foreign key
pricing another table with  product id and store id as foreign keys

just a brief idea !!

Comment: How did you categorise the products. Mine is:

(Phones, Tablets, Laptops, .. etc) and an ttribute in each item will tell its specifications (Manufacturer: Samsung, Memory: 16GB) so that I can do filteration based on these attributes or specifications.

Comment: i am not your db designer . thats just a sample data . DUMMY data